# EclipseLink JPA 2.1 User supplied connection

Tags: java, database-connection, eclipselink, user-defined

I would like to use EclipseLink as my JPA engine.
We are using a subclass of java.sql.Connection and I would like to know if I can force EclipseLink to use my connection. I would like to set the connection object programmatically.

Something like

```
MyConnection conn = new MyConnection(JDBC_URL, USR, PWD);
EntityManagerFactory factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(conn);
```

Comment: Is this question still open and valid for your needs?

Answer (score 1):

You can set a custom connection programatically using the following code:

```
Map properties = new HashMap();

// Configure the internal EclipseLink connection pool
properties.put(JDBC_DRIVER, "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
properties.put(JDBC_URL, "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:ORCL");
properties.put(JDBC_USER, "user-name");
properties.put(JDBC_PASSWORD, "password");
Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("unit-name", properties);
```

*I found this answer here after a quick google search:*

http://eclipse.1072660.n5.nabble.com/Defining-persistence-xml-programatically-td2536.html

I dont believe that there is a way to force Eclipselink to connect using only that `java.sql.Connection`; not out of the box at least. You could make a simple utility method to pass in said connection and build a properties map as I described above.

```
public Map convertConnectionToProperties(Connection conn) {
    // Do the mapping

    return theMap;
}
```

If you take a look at [this link](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/Persistence.html) you will see that

## Persistence.java

```
createEntityManagerFactory(String persistenceUnitName) 
createEntityManagerFactory(String persistenceUnitName, Map properties)
```

That is all it can take as parameters. Simply put; what you are asking for simply isn't possible without taking your connection object and adjust it to return something that complies with what `createEntityManagerFactory` can take in.

```
class MyConnection {
     // Your code here
    
    public Map convertToMap() {
        // Do the mapping

        return theMap;
    }

    public String getPersistenceUnitName() {
        return "Some-Name";
    }
}
```

And then utilize it like this:

```
MyConnection conn = new MyConnection(JDBC_URL, USR, PWD);
EntityManagerFactory factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(conn.getPersistenceUnitName(), conn.convertToMap());
```

Comment: In your code I'm not passing my connection to the engine, I am configuring  it to connect to the database using the parameters that are put in the map. I would like to force EclipseLink to use the instance of Connection I'm using (because it's a subclass of java.sql.Connection and we are provided with it).

Comment: For those that are wondering what the constants `JDBC_DRIVER` etc are. They are strings with the same values as the property names in your persistence.xml file. For example `JDBC_DRIVER = "javax.persistence.jdbc.driver"`, `JDBC_URL = "javax.persistence.jdbc.url"`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

<sup>* This solution use Spring Framework.</sup>

#### javax.sql.DataSource

First you need to *wrap* your connection in a `javax.sql.DataSource`, e.g.:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDataSource;

public class MyDataSource extends AbstractDataSource {

    private static final String JDBC_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/test";
    private static final String USR = "root";
    private static final String PWD = "";

    public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
        return new MyConnection(JDBC_URL, USR, PWD);
    }

    public Connection getConnection(String username, String password)
            throws SQLException {
        return new MyConnection(JDBC_URL, USR, PWD);
    }
}
```

To avoid overwriting all methods, you can extend an existing class in Spring.

#### javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory

```
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;

import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean bean =
                new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        bean.setDataSource(new MyDataSource());
        bean.setPersistenceUnitName("TestPU");
        bean.setJpaVendorAdapter(new EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter());
        bean.afterPropertiesSet();

        EntityManagerFactory factory = bean.getNativeEntityManagerFactory();
        EntityManager em = factory.createEntityManager();
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        User user = new User();
        user.setFullname("Mister");
        em.persist(user);
        em.getTransaction().commit();
        em.close();
    }

}
```

---

**NOTES**

- You may want to need add the next property in your `persistence.xml`:

  ```
  <property name="eclipselink.weaving" value="false"/>
  ```
- I used a Standalone Maven Project for test the code and the dependencies in the `pom.xml` looks like this:

  ```
  <dependencies>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>mysql</groupId>
          <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
          <version>5.1.31</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
          <version>4.0.5.RELEASE</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
          <version>4.0.5.RELEASE</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
          <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.1</version>
      </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  ```

  Or if you prefer, the required jars:

  ```
  mysql-connector-java-5.1.31.jar
  spring-context-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar
  spring-aop-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar
  aopalliance-1.0.jar
  spring-beans-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar
  spring-core-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar
  commons-logging-1.1.3.jar
  spring-expression-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar
  spring-orm-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar
  spring-jdbc-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar
  spring-tx-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar
  eclipselink-2.5.1.jar
  javax.persistence-2.1.0.jar
  commonj.sdo-2.1.1.jar
  ```

Comment: Nice! I would really like to use Spring for this project but unfortunately that's not possible..