# How to use JPA with a random database i.e., user submitted

Tags: java, sql, xml, jpa

I am using UCanAccess and was setting up my Entities and Persistence Unit when I realized that the DB location is hard coded into the PU.xml (which is fine to build my entities, but I need to have it variable).

I am creating an application that will be given to people that will need to access their own db's, but this is a random path.

I am curious how exactly I would be able to change the information in the PU?

The only way I can think of is somhow editing the xml file,  or creating the xml file on the fly.

Anyone have any idea how I can do this?

It's simple using regular java.sql commands, so I would expect it to work easy with JPA as well.

thanks all!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done by leveraging the database connection properties (credentials and all that) to a data source that will use connection pooling. You can provide the data source in 3 ways:

1. Directly in the XML file. JPA will try to obtain the Data Source from JNDI. This is useful when working in an application server like JBoss/Wildfly or GlassFish, or even in a servlet container like Tomcat. The downside of this approach is that this isn't easy to replicate in Java SE environment, basically because you will have to provide a JNDI provider and all the stuff this implies. Your persistence.xml will look as follows:

   ```xml
   <persistence-unit name="foo-PU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
       <!-- the provider: Hibernate, EclipseLink or another -->
       <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
       <!-- JNDI name of your datasource -->
       <non-jta-data-source>jdbc/myds</non-jta-data-source>
       <!-- class definitions here -->
       <!-- if working with hibernate, you should provide the dialect -->
       <properties>
           <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect"/>
       </properties>
   </persistence-unit>
   ```
2. Provide the database connection properties programatically when creating the `EntityManagerFactory`. Note that this approach depends heavily on the JPA vendor. This is how you can do it in EclipseLink (from http://eclipse.1072660.n5.nabble.com/Defining-persistence-xml-programatically-td2536.html):

   ```
   import static org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.config.PersistenceUnitProperties.*;

   Map properties = new HashMap();

   // Configure the internal EclipseLink connection pool
   properties.put(JDBC_DRIVER, "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
   properties.put(JDBC_URL, "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:ORCL");
   properties.put(JDBC_USER, "user-name");
   properties.put(JDBC_PASSWORD, "password");
   Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("unit-name", properties);
   ```

   Personally, this looks very ugly and unpleasant, specially because JPA vendor will create a physical connection when creating an `EntityManager`. This is why I would recommend wrapping the database properties into a datasource like C3P0 or BoneCP. In this example, I use BoneCP to set the datasource programatically (thus focusing on setting a single property) and then pass it as property to create the EntityManagerFactory (this is a basic adaptation of my real code used in production, so forgive the bad design =\ ):

   persistence.xml:

   ```
   <persistence-unit name="foo-PU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
       <!-- the provider: Hibernate, EclipseLink or another -->
       <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>

       <!-- class definitions here -->
   </persistence-unit>
   ```

   Two methods: 1 to create the DataSource and another to create the EntityManagerFactory.

   ```
   public final class EntityManagerFactoryCreator {
       private static DataSource getDataSource(String properties) {
           Properties conf = new Properties();
           try {
               conf.load(
                   DataSourceFactory.class
                   .getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(
                       properties));
           } catch (IOException e) {
               //handle the error
               //naive handling shown here
               e.printStacktrace();
           }
           BoneCPDataSource dataSource = new BoneCPDataSource();
           dataSource.setDriverClass(conf.getProperty("db.driver"));
           dataSource.setJdbcUrl(conf.getProperty("db.url"));
           dataSource.setUsername(conf.getProperty("db.user"));
           dataSource.setPassword(conf.getProperty("db.password"));
           dataSource.setIdleConnectionTestPeriodInMinutes(
               Long.parseLong(
                   conf.getProperty("db.bonecp.idleConnectionTestPeriod")));
           dataSource.setIdleMaxAgeInSeconds(
               Long.parseLong(
                   conf.getProperty("db.bonecp.idleMaxAge")));
           dataSource.setMaxConnectionsPerPartition(
               Integer.parseInt(
                   conf.getProperty("db.bonecp.maxConnections")));
           //more properties to load...
           return dataSource;
       }

       public static EntityManagerFactory createEMF() {
           Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
           String dataSourceKey = "";
           //using Hibernate
           //dataSourceKey = org.hibernate.cfg.AvailableSettings.DATASOURCE;
           //using EclipseLink
           //dataSourceKey = org.eclipse.persistence
           //    .config.PersistenceUnitProperties.NON_JTA_DATASOURCE;
           properties.put(
               dataSourceKey,
               getDataSource("mysql-con.properties"));
           return Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("foo-PU", properties);
       }
   }
   ```

   A `mysql-con.properties` configuration file that contains the connection properties:

   ```
   db.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
   db.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/foo_db
   db.user=user
   db.password=s3cr3t
   db.bonecp.idleConnectionTestPeriod=60
   db.bonecp.idleMaxAge=240
   db.bonecp.maxConnections=10
   # more properties...
   ```

   The code above works in both Java SE and Java EE environments and you don't need to provide a JNDI datasource for it and can be enhanced to support different data sources pointing to more databases (just create more properties files depending on your database configurations and reuse the code). The downside is that it has a tight coupling with JPA vendor as shown in the value of `dataSourceKey` variable.
3. Use a dependency injection framework like Spring or CDI that can helps you providing the data source for your `EntityManagerFactory`. I can't provide a solution out of the box for this approach since I haven't tested it (yet), but there are plenty tutorials on the net for this.

Choose the best option based on your needs for your project.

Comment: @user3599960 I do recommend method 2 but I explain that the downside is that you're still tied to the implementation from JPA vendor for the exact name of the properties. Method 3 will do the same but behind the scenes for you. Also, method 2 can (and should) be improved to become a more flexible approach. Currently I'm using method 2 for a proof of concept against performance and other quality attributes to evaluate some JPA vendors for usage in new projects.

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed answers.

The second and third examples seem to be the best for my needs, but you don't seem to recommend #2?

Basically I am connecting to their databases to grab information on image locations, and that's all.  I am not doing hardcore database manipulation.

I also will be connecting to a MYSQL DB on my server (don't know if this matters).

This is a tiny application that is part of a bigger application.

I figured this information might be important.  I understand why you are saying #2 COULD be bad, but would I be able to use #2 in this case as it seems easier?

Comment: @user3599960 method 2 is not bad, but it's in a basic form and can be adapted depending on your needs. IMO it works as is but the design can be greatly enhanced to support more use cases that will depend on your needs, like connecting to different databases. If you ask me if I would use method 2 for a simple application, I would say yes :).

Comment: Sorry I was editing my comment.


 It doesn't really matter if I'm tied to the vendor imo since this is such a small application?  I'm assuming this is just the normal approach as we want to be as Cross Platform as possible, but this is going to be used on Windows only machines.

So what could be improved on #2?  It seems straight forward. 

I will probably go with method 2 if you think that for my project it would suffice.  I rather not have to download and work with extra stuff if not needed (especially since this is the last step in this project).  I will definitely look into it in the futu

Comment: @user3599960 I think my last comment provides that answer.

Comment: Damn this commenting is messing up, I'm sorry, you're very fast to reply :P.

Yeah, this is a very simple application.  Just connect, grab a couple pieces of data, and then close.

Thank you very much for your time, I am going to test this out now, and will be back if I have any more questions :).



EDIT:  Guess you posted before me again... sigh :P thanks again haha.



You would post your answer while I was asking the question... Editing FTL :(.

Comment: @user3599960 sure, I'll be attending your comments.

Comment: I do have some other important info to add... 

Since I am using this to connect to their DB, but also to my MYSQL DB on my server, is there any issue with having these 2 connections?

I would be using 2 different entity managers (which I'm assuming is correct)?

Also, I didn't think about this before, but there is a possibility that they might have more than one database, but would only be connecting to one db at a time.  Would I create the entitymanager then do w/e i needed to do, close it, then connect that same em to the new db so I don't have a bunch of them hanging around?
thx

Comment: `EntityManager` is related to a `Connection`, while `EntityManagerFactory` is related to the connection provider. If you need to connect to 2 different databases (regardless the database engine) then you should have 2 `EntityManagerFactory`s.

Comment: So I should just create new emf's and em's for each db I connect to i.e., 

          EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("pu1");

  EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();   

          EntityManagerFactory emf2 = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("pu2");

  EntityManager em2 = emf2.createEntityManager();     

...


does anything happen to the old factories?  It seems that the connection connects when you do em.getTransaction().begin(); and then commit ends it, so as long as that is good we shouldn't have to worry  about a lot of emfs/ems?

Thank you.

Comment: @user3599960 about `EntityManagerFactory`s, you're correct. About commit, you need to explicitly commit by using `em.getTransaction().commit()`. The connection will close when you perform `em.close()` and the database pool (the physical connections) will close when you call `emf.close()`.

Comment: One more question, I just tried running the code after doing what I needed to and I got a 

Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named

I tried doing                 properties.put( "provider" , "org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider");

As indicated by this article http://java-persistence.blogspot.com/2008/02/testing-eclipselink-jpa-in-javase.html

but the error still persists...

I believe I had this error for my last Persistence Unit, but I forgot I how I dealt with it....

Comment: From what I see I also have an issue saying which class my entity is.

I was thinking about connecting to an already created PU and it seems to work except I got an error about a file not existing(which is my fault) but it did connect to the EM according to 

[EL Info]: 2014-10-08 21:44:10.505--ServerSession(2057435429)--EclipseLink, version: Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd
[EL Severe]: ejb: 2014-10-08 21:44:10.59--ServerSession(2057435429)--Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): 


So could I create an entity like (below)

Comment: <persistence-unit name="AccessPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <class>.Items</class>
    <properties>
//or get rid of the properties tag since there are none.
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>

and just adding the properties in using the map?

Thoughts?

Thanks :)

Comment: I would need to know about your exact code. Please post a different question for it.

Comment: Here is the new post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26285115/issue-defining-persistence-programatically-met-with-no-provider-found

Thank you for everything Luiggi.

Answer (score 0):

Probably impossible if you want to use the "standard" JPA with `persistence.xml`.

However, if your application is building on top of Spring, you can simply inject correct value to `LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean` (Datasource, Dialect, etc) and everything should work.

Just to pay attention that your application should avoid using native SQL because that is not portable in most case.

Answer (score 0):

You can setup a dynamic `EntityManagerFactory` by passing in a properties object like so:

```
Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("unit-name", properties);
```

You can check out a more detailed answer of mine on a similar question:

[EclipseLink JPA 2.1 User supplied connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24452376/eclipselink-jpa-2-1-user-supplied-connection/24452758#24452758)